# How to convert comma separated string into numeric(integer) array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I need to convert a string with multiple numbers to an array in jQuery. My string is the one below:

```
var strVal = "901,235,342,421,345,745,544,324,445,123,232,986,345,678";
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jquery for this

```js
var strVal = "901,235,342,421,345,745,544,324,445,123,232,986,345,678";
var result = strVal.split(",").map(x=>+x);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with `','` and then [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with to [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) converted values

```js
var strVal = "901,235,342,421,345,745,544,324,445,123,232,986,345,678",
    numbers = strVal.split(',').map(Number);

console.log(numbers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: *Upvote* for the CSS trick to make the console's view better, really nice!